# Exclude tags inside tags with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the text between two tags, but exclude any other tags that are inside, for example:

```
$text = "<h3><p>I dont want this text</p>But I do want this!</h3><p>some other text that I dont want</p>";
```

The only thing I need is `<h3>But I do want this!</h3>`, and ALL other tags that could be inside there should be excluded.

Is this possible with preg_match/preg_replace?

All I have at the moment:

```
if(preg_match("/<h3>(.*)<\/h3>/s", $text, $match)){
    $text = $match[0];
}

$text = preg_replace("#<\s*img[^>]*>#", "", $text);
```

Comment: Have you tried something or are you just asking for code?

Comment: I have been able to get the h3 tag with preg_match, and then for example remove an image tag with preg_replace, but I want to do this with all the possible standard tags.

Comment: Show some code effort that you did already?

Comment: I suggest you have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1301076 and then use http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: You really have that (broken) HTML? `p` ist not allowed inside `h3`.

Comment: It is just an example, think of any tag you like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex you can try:

`(?:<(h\d)>[^<>]*?)(?:<(?!\2).*>)\K(.+?)<\/\1>`

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/nF6bS2/1).

Group 2 holds what you need.

You might also have cases when there is text directly after the opening tag. Then, I'd use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/nF6bS2/2):

`(?:<(h\d)>([^<>]*?))(?:<(?!\2).*>)\K(.+?)<\/\1>`

Just combine Group 2 and Group 3.

Here is a sample code that works in [Tutorialspoint](http://goo.gl/OQkhvI):

```
<?php
    $re = "/(?:<(h\\d)>([^<>]*?))(?:<(?!\\2).*>)\\K(.+?)(?=<\\/\\1>)/"; 
    $str = "<h3>Maybe this, too. <p>I dont want this text</p><p>I dont want this text</p>But I do want this!</h3><p>some other text that I dont want</p>"; 
    preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
    $group2 = each($matches[2]);
    $group3 = each($matches[3]);
    print_r($group2["value"]);
    print_r($group3["value"]);
?>
```